# createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent will unlock after pressing the back button numerous times in a row?

Tags: android, fingerprint

I recently implemented fingerprint authentication into one of my apps.  Everything works as expected except for this one problem that I discovered when testing. Some background: I generated a key with the following key gen parameters:

```
KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                    .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                    .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                    .setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(80)
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
```

so the user will remain authenticated for 80 seconds. Any time the app needs to re-verify the user, it will check if the key is still valid, and otherwise `createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent` if the key timed out, which brings up a system screen prompting the user to authenticate their fingerprint or enter a password/pin/pattern.

The problem: Now this screen should be un-cancelable, however if I tap the back button or top arrow button multiple times in a row, the user gets into the app. Has anyone had this experience?

**EDIT:** 
This seems to only be happening on Samsung devices I tested, it works well on the Nexus and Google Pixel.
Here is the code being used, it's from the Google sample project on using createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent.
This is the method to check the if the key is still valid.

```
 protected boolean tryEncrypt() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            try {
                mKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
                mKeyStore.load(null);
                SecretKey secretKey = (SecretKey) mKeyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME, null);
                mCipher = Cipher.getInstance(
                        KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/" + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/"
                                + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
                mCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
                mCipher.doFinal(SECRET_BYTE_ARRAY);
                return true;
            } catch (UserNotAuthenticatedException e) {
                // User is not authenticated, let's authenticate with device credentials.
                showAuthenticationScreen();
                return false;
            } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {
                return false;
            } catch (BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | KeyStoreException |
                    CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException
                    | NoSuchPaddingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Here is the showEncryption method that is called if the key is timed out:

```
  protected void showAuthenticationScreen() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            Intent intent = getKeyguardManager().createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(null, null);
            if (intent != null) {
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please share code, when you check authentication in your app

Comment: Check my edit above